# How to decompress gzip data?

Tags: java, arrays, gzip

I have a byte array and I want to decompress this byte array. When I run below code it gives;

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
```

I get this byte array from a soap webservice. When I call this webservice from soap UI it returns;

```
<size>491520</size>
<studentData>
    <dataContent>Uy0xMDAwMF90MTAwMDAtVXNlciBTZWN1cml0eSBB........</dataContent>
</studentData>
```

Is there a problem with data coming from web service or my decompress method?

```
public static byte[] decompress(final byte[] input) throws Exception{

    try (ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
            GZIPInputStream gzipper = new GZIPInputStream(bin)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int len;
        while ((len = gzipper.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        gzipper.close();
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I decoded base64 and write it to a file called "test.gzip". Now I can extract this file with 7zip and I can see all student files without any problem.

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(studentData.getDataContent());
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.gzip");
fos.write(decoded);
fos.close();
```

But when I try to decompress this decoded file it still gives same error;

```
decompress(decoded);
```

Comment: this looks like base64.

Comment: It's not Zip. It's base64 of what seems to be plain text.

Comment: @njzk2 I edited my answer.

Comment: Well, it's still not zip. If you decode it, you get a plain text. Write it to a file with extension ".txt" and open it in an editor, and you'll see the text.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can't see a text but some unidentified characters.

Comment: Maybe you have base64 in SOAP response and gzipped data in the base64-data?

Comment: I decoded the string `Uy0xMDAwMF90MTAwMDAtVXNlciBTZWN1cml0eSBB` from your example and it gives `S-10000_t10000-User Security A` as the decoded value. That's plain text.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes when I update my file extension to ".txt" the text starts with "10000_t10000-User Security A" but then it goes with unidentified characters. This file is not plain text I think because When I save this file as test.gzip and extract it with 7zip It exports 3-4 files and some subfolders and I can read this files without any problem.

Comment: If it starts with that text then it's definitely not a gzip file. It could be that 7zip identifies it as something else or knows how to skip the text part.

Comment: Provide more base64 so that we can see what comes after the text.